# How to clear svn client cache? (Odd problems when debugging svn configs for different users/roles)

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, svn, mod-dav-svn

I recently setup a SVN server with http as transport protocol (apache2, dav_svn,etc. ). The server seems to be working fine. I also created an authz file and various users. Now I want to debug, if my configuration is working as expected.

When I access the svn via a web browser as different users ("admin"/"user") I see the expected directories. No problem. I guess the server configuration is correct.

However, I experienced something very strange on my client machine (which is a Mac) when using the svn tool on the shell:

```
svn co hxxp://user@a.b.c.d/mysvn userdir
```

... returns the correct directories or files the user should see.

```
svn co hxxp://admin@a.b.c.d/mysvn admindir
```

... returns the correct directories or files the admin should see.

I delete userdir and rerun

```
svn co hxxp://user@a.b.c.d/mysvn userdir
```

... now USER has access to all files; also to those files she should not see.

I checked back in the web browser and here everything is as expected. I am a tiny bit confused. Is this some kind of odd caching problem on client side of the svn tool? How can I purge the cache?

I googled quite a bit to find a solution but nothing came close to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like syntax of the svn co command was faulty.

It seems to be working with

svn co --username user hxxp://a.b.c.d/mysvn/ userdir

Comment: can your mark your answer as valid ? thanks

Comment: System telling me: You can acccept your own answer tomorrow.